# Are Python decorators necessary?

Tags: python, decorator

I have a basic understanding of decorators, but as yet they seem superfluous and "hacky", like C macros but for functions.

[An article](https://www.oreilly.com/ideas/5-reasons-you-need-to-learn-to-write-python-decorators) stressing the importance of decorators gives this example of decorator usage:

```py
from myapp.log import logger

def log_order_event(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        logger.info("Ordering: %s", func.__name__)
        order = func(*args, **kwargs)
        logger.debug("Order result: %s", order.result)
        return order
    return wrapper

@log_order_event
def order_pizza(*toppings):
    # let's get some pizza!
```

`order_pizza(*toppings) # Usage`

Isn't this equivalent to the decoratorless code below?

```py
from myapp.log import logger

def log_order_event(func, *args, **kwargs):
    logger.info("Ordering: %s", func.__name__)
    order = func(*args, **kwargs)
    logger.debug("Order result: %s", order.result)
    return order

def order_pizza(*toppings):
    # let's get some pizza!
```

`log_order_event(order_pizza, *toppings) # Usage`

In fact, isn't the second snippet easier to write since it's one function instead of a function *and* a wrapper function? The usage calls *are* longer, but they more clearly indicate what's actually being called.

Is it purely a matter of taste and syntactic sugar, or am I missing something?

Comment: this question is not really a good fit for Stackoverflow ... you are correct that those two statements are basically equivalent... you are also right that it is simply syntactic sugar and preference

Comment: What do you think about scaling this? If you have tons of functions and require tracking or a similar operation on each one (for example).

Comment: The decoratorless code requires you to call an unrelated function to get the behaviour you want to come along with it. Think about the difference when you’re adding this decorator after other code already uses your function. (And decorators are just a neat syntax for calling a function and replacing the name after defining the function, e.g. `order_pizza = log_order_event(order_pizza)`, so very much not a hack.)

Comment: No, using higher-order functions is not hacky and is not like a macro. The `@syntax` is just sugar for `order_pizza = log_order_event(order_pizza)`.

Comment: Decorators are a way of adding metadata/behavior to annotated stuff, be it function, class, method, whatever. The fact of python use high order functions is a implementation detail

Comment: @geckos well, to be more precise, it is adding behavior, "decorating" *callables*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga on python is more behavior, on java and php you add metadata, and use reflection to grab that metadata and do whatever you want, the whole idea behind decorator is to tag things with behavior/metadata

Comment: @geckos Python decorators and Java annotations aren't the same thing. They simply share a syntax. Python decorators are specifically for adding *behavior* to callables.

Comment: I mean, strictly speaking the only thing *necessary* is machine code. You can always make this argument, you don't *need* functions, arrays, etc, heck you don't even need variables. All of these things are *merely* abstractions to help the programmer

Comment: annotations and decorators have some in common, IMHO, they are the same concept

Comment: Best question so far in SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both snippets are equivalent as far as behavior is concerned. However, I'd use the decorator version for two main reasons:

1. **Readability**: With snippet 2, you'd require an explicit function call to a *less relevant method* `log_order_event()` whose main purpose is logging. This logging functionality may be required by other methods such as `order_appetizers()` and therefore, you would require individual calls to `log_order_event()` for every such method. Wouldn't it be better(from a readability perspective) to have a wrapper defined once & for all, that performs logging and you may call the wrapper(as a decorator) for such methods whenever necessary? Decorators are syntactic sugar but certainly not a hack. In fact, [PEP 318](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/#id67) clearly talks about the motivation behind decorators, you must read that.
2. **Scalability**: Consider a situation where your code has several methods(say 20) such as `order_appetizers()`, `order_maincourse()`, `order_desserts()` and so on. Let's also assume that you'd like to perform some prior checks before ordering any of these items, say check for toppings(for pizza's), calories(for desserts) and so on. When using decorators, its just a matter of defining the wrapper functions in a separate wrapper class for each check, import it in your main code and decorate the required methods respectively. That way, your wrapper functions are completely isolated and the main logic remains clean and easy to maintain.

   ```
   @check_toppings
   @log_order_event
   def order_pizza(*toppings):
       # let's get some pizza!

   @check_calories
   @log_order_event
   def order_desserts():
       # let's order some desserts!
   ...and so on for 20 more methods
   ```

   With a decoratorless logic, while you can separate the *check*(and log) methods in a separate class and import in your main logic, you would still have to add individual calls to each of these methods inside each *order* method which from a code maintenance perspective could prove to be daunting, especially for new eyes.